# A subgroup is normal iff it is invariant under every inner automorphism. How to prove that An⊴Sn.

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Well i know how to prove using the index method but i have no idea of proving this by using the above condition.

Comment: The condition mentioned is just the usual definition of being normal (or at least one of them). It follows easily from the fact that sign is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For any $\;\pi\in A_n\,,\,\,\,\sigma\in S_n\;$ , what is the sign of $\;\sigma^{-1}\pi\sigma\;$ ?

Comment: can you please provide me with the detailed solution

Comment: @krishneel Nop. The above is more than enough if you manage the basic definitions. For example: (1) Who **exactly** are the elements of $\;A_n\;$ in $\;S_n\;$ ? What does being "a normal subgroup of a group" actually means? What does the above hint gives you. See?  Voilá !

Answer (score 0):

$A_n$ is released as the kernel of the signature on $S_n$, whence is normal.

Another way to see it, $A_n$ has index $2$ in $S_n$.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a very good idea to use gothic german letters... if you want to be widely understood, that is.

Comment: I took account of your remark. I thought it was a universal convention to use gothic german letters for permutations subgroups.

Comment: Unless you work with the excellent book of Huppert's "Endliche Gruppen I", no: it really is not.